# Android supporting all tablets - categorize drawables and layouts

Tags: android, screen-resolution, resourcebundle

I have seen many thread discussing this problem in stackoverflow (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093194/supporting-all-android-tablets-resolutions), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148420/android-layouts-drawables-and-resolution-what-is-the-best-way) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293436/android-layouts-design-for-tablets-and-devices)), and I have read the documentation about supporting multiple screens, and designs. But I am still not clear about the folder structure for drawables and layout for different screens

I am working on an app that support android phone and tablets. And my project showing some images, which need to be shown in good quality in all possible android devices. And I need to tell my designer to design for all these resolutions.

From the documentation it seems I should add drawables for following resolutions (drawable folder name is given at the end),

```
1) 240 x 320  - Phone LDPI  -> drawable-ldpi

2) 320 x 480  - Phone MDPI  -> drawable-mdpi

3) 480 x 800  - Phone HDPI  -> drawable-hdpi

//Now for tablets

4) 1024x600   - Tablet LDPI -> ??

5) 1280x800   - Tablet MDPI -> ??

6) 1536x1152  - Tablet HDPI -> ??

7) 2560x1600  - Tablet XHDPI-> ??
```

From supporting [multiple screens documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), it seems I can use folders like

```
1) drawable-sw600dp  ( a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).)
2) drawable-sw720dp   (a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

But what about tablets with resolutions in the range of 1536x1152, 2560x1600 etc.. the 10' resolution range (720 x 1280 etc)seems small for them.. My client has a Nexus 10 with resolution 2560×1600 and I want my app to look perfect on it..

I know about, nine patch images, layout using `wrap_content` and other good practices like that. But for this project, I have some images which, as per requirement, should be seen lazer sharp on all common screens, and I need several versions of those images at least in my bundle.

So what and what resolutions should I mention to the designer? And how can I categorize them in bundle giving correct folder name.

Comment: Check out the wordpress app. it might give you some idea on how to handle diff screens https://android.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually Tablets are categorized by size not by dpi, i.e 7" tab is `drawable-large` while your 10" tab is `drawable-xlarge`. And now you can again categorized by dpi like `drawable-large-hdpi` which means it is a Tab of 7" which having High Density.

you can use `SW` smallest width concept to target that, see [Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen) and make calculation for the same.

Tablet Tablets are categorized into two size.

> 7" (1024X(600-48(navigation bar))) = 1024 X 552 (drawable-large)
>       10" (1280X(800-48(navigation bar))) = 1280 X 752 (drawable-xlarge)

and for 2560x1600 calculate SW dp with formula

> px= Device's width
>   dpi= Device's density

formula given

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

interchange formula if you have px's value

```
dp = px / (dpi / 160)
```

so drawable-swxxxdp will do the job

Comment: and also see the developer site [DeclaringTabletLayouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

Comment: So I would say, I should tell the designer to design for  1) 1024 x 768 (drawable-large folder) 2) 1280 x 800 (drawable-xlarge folder)  3) 2560x1600 (use drawable-xlarge-xhdpi folder). Will it covers almost all screens?

Comment: No, its very difficult to cover all Tab screen because there are many. see my updated answer

Comment: One more doubt, what is the navigation (status bar height?) of a nexus 10 tab (I mean any tab with 2560 x 1600) resolution in portrait/landscape mode? Any way to find it using any calculation?

Comment: had done some R&D(month ago) seems it is the same but not very sure about nexus 10 Tab, will back to you if any new update avails

Comment: Here's my current implementation. I have 3 set of folders for drawables. drawable, drawable-sw600dp-mdpi (x 4 densities), drawable-sw720dp-mdpi(x 4 densities) for phone, 7" and 10" tabs respectively. Total of 12 folders of images. but my 10" galaxy tab GT-P7500 (1280x800) seems to pick up images from sw720dp-XXHDPI folder instead of sw720dp-MDPI folder. However when i use only 1 set of folders without swXXXdp qualifiers its picking up correctly from DRAWABLE-MDPI folder . What could be the possible issue ?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there are two kinds variables for device display : pixel density and screen dimensions.
Both are theoretically independent, though in market both vary together from *low end* to *high end* devices.

Pixel density demands for different bitmap resolutions and level of detail (36X36 to 96X96 icons for example) .

Screen dimensions demand for better use of real estate ( Multi activity layout for phones, combined fragmented layout for tablets, for example). Not as important as pixel density, but  good to have, because tablet users might find a phone layout too bland, and waste of screen space.

So:

- To cover most pixel densities you will have to have different
  [versions of drawables](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) : `ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi`.  Prefer nine-patch drawables, these are a lot better at fitting everywhere.
- To cover most screen sizes you will have to have different [layout arrangements](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html), and a [responsive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) [layout design](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) for `small,large and xlarge` values. Also, different layouts for portrait, and landscape orientations are good to have sometimes.
- Android lets you mix configuration combinations too. E.g. `drawable-large-hdpi` etc.
- Avoid hard coded pixel co-ordinated and dimensions at all costs, use density or percentage.
- Its *Way better* to have one flexible nine-patch drawable than to have different drawables for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use xxhdpi for drawables like drawable-xxhdpi

xxhdpi (480dpi, Android 4.1 or later)

Or refer "Android Tabular Column" in the follwing link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartphone

Answer (score 1):

What I have come to use is:

- one layout folder (or second one: layout-land)
- a few values folders with dimens.xml (-hdpi, -large, -xlarge) for different sizes, fonts etc.
- drawables: -hdpi with most images, they scale down for all the phones; -large for 7" tablets; -xlarge for 10" tablets. Or just -hdpi and -large.

I might verify this approach, i.e. use -sw600dp and -sw720dp but for now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Hello i think android drawable resolution is-

10"   - 1280 X 800

7"    - 1024 X 600

xhdpi - 960  x 720

hdpi  - 800  X 480

mdpi  - 480  X 320

Comment: Density has very little to do with resolution